# how to load imageview,textview,webview in detailview controller when we selected the row of masterview controller

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I am new in objective C. In my app I had created splitviewcontroller, first view is master view followed by detailview. In master view row I have some lists of thumbnail of data like images, pdf files, folders etc..

What I want to do when we select on row of masterview which have image thumbnail, the image will be displayed in detail view. Like same when we select on pdf(document) thumbnail in the row it open in detailview, but when we select on row which contains folder it will navigate in masterview to open new table view.

Answer (score 0):

Best for this will be to use a [delegate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) pattern.

When element is selected in the left view, call the delegate to notify the right view that it should show image of selected item - you can also pass item itself to detailed view, just in case you need more data later.